# What does "tags whose commits are reachable from the specified commit" mean?

Tags: git, sorting, tags, branch, git-tag

In one of my projects, I am trying to get the most recent tag after checking out a branch, or from `origin/master`. If I run `git tag -l --sort=-creatordate --merged | head -n1` or a `git describe`, I get the same result, but its from a tag from far in the past. If i get rid of the `--merged`, it shows the correct, most recent tag in the project.

Checking out a specific branch gives me back the correct, last known tag in the repo, but if its from `origin/master` or `FETCH_HEAD`, it gives me one in the past.

I'm mainly wondering how the `--merged` flag works, because the manual pages just says it `Only list tags whose commits are reachable from the specified commit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

- the general concept of *reachability*, and
- how `git tag -l --merged` works, which uses the concept itself.

[Reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) is a property of a *graph*, or in Git's case, a *directed graph*.  Consult either the Wikipedia article, or [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), for a proper explanation.  (Or see one of my many StackOverflow answers showing how to determine which branches *contain* various commits.)  The rest of this assumes you already understand reachability.

A *tag*, in Git, is just a fancy pointer: in effect, an arrow pointing to one particular commit.  But there's one other special thing about tags in Git:  They can point to a *tag object*, rather than directly to a commit.<sup>1</sup>  The tag object has the annotations for `git tag -a` or message for `git tag -m`.  The tag object then holds the raw hash ID of the underlying commit.

This brings us to the wording in the documentation:

> the manual pages just says [`--merged`]
>
> > Only list tags whose commits are reachable from the specified commit.

We run:

```
git tag -l --merged <commit-specifier>
```

so we pick one commit.  That's the "specified commit".

The `git tag -l` operation will now iterate through every tag.  The tag either points directly to a commit, or to an annotated tag object that points to a commit.  That commit exists somewhere in the overall Git commit graph.  The question that `--merged` applies is: *can we reach the tagged commit from the specified commit?*

If we *can* reach the tagged commit, `git tag -l` lists the tag.  If not (or if we must skip the tag because it does not tag a commit after all), `git tag -l` omits the tag.

---

<sup>1</sup>A tag name is actually allowed to point to a tree or blob object, as well as to a commit or annotated tag object.  In this case there is no commit at all, and `git tag -l --merged` will just ignore that tag.  Also, an annotated tag object can actually refer to any other kind of object, not just a commit object.  So the true rule for resolving a tag name is:

- If tag name refers to an annotated tag object, switch to that annotated tag object.
- While we have an annotated tag object, switch to the object that is the target of this annotated tag.  (Git refers to this internally as *peeling* tags, analogous to peeling an onion, layer by layer.)
- Stop: we have an object.

We now know the object to which the tag refers.  If it's a commit, it's a candidate for this `--merged` listing.  If not, it's not.